# How to set access token in cookie of WKWebview to avoid login

Tags: ios, swift, sharepoint

I have one application in which we are fetching Sharepoint web pages and the app is MSAL framework in build.

After MSAL authentication we are getting the access token after that we are loading some Sharepoint web pages to WKWebview which needs to log in first.

If I have already MSAL access token so how can I pass that access token in WKWebview to avoid the login in browser.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView has its own cookie storage, you can access it trough:

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
```

You can then set any cookie you need

```
let store = WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
store.setCookie(<YourCookie>)
```